# Black pixels in renders

Tags: rendering

So I'm a newbie in Blender, and when I rendered the model, there were some annoying black pixels. Can you help me?[image: Yep, roblox lmao]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have those faces duplicated...look into z-fighting if you want to [read more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). You may need to delete duplicate objects (some may only be visible in render), or you may need to remove doubles (<kbd>w</kbd> key menu in edit mode).